# How to fix error argument of type undefined is not assignable to parameter of type 'string or () => string usng typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am getting error error argument of type undefined is not assignable to parameter of type 'string or () => string usng typescript and react.

below is my code,

```
export const useSomething =()=> {
    const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState<string>(
        undefined //getting error here
    );
    const toggle = (itemId: string) => {
        setItemId(itemId);
        return {toggle, itemId};

    }
 }


 function  Parent() {
     const {itemId, toggle} = useSomething();
     return (
        <Child anotherId={anotherId} itemId={itemId} toggle={toggle}/>         
     );
 }


 function Child({itemId, anotherId, toggle) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={() => toggle(anotherId || '')/>
    );
 }
```

i am not sure what is causing this error.could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the initial value of the state member to `undefined`, which isn't a string. So to fix it, you have to either:

1. Initialize the state member with a string, instead of `undefined`;

   ```
    const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState<string>(
        "" // <=== or whatever string makes sense as the initial value
    );
   ```

   or
2. Change the type of the state member to `string | undefined` (a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types)), which allows the member to be a string *or* be `undefined`:

   ```
    const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState<string | undefined>(
        undefined // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^
    );
   ```

---

Side note: If you're initializing to `undefined`, you can just leave the argument off entirely: `= useState<string|undefined>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you initialize the state with `undefined`, the type of the state is not `string` but rather `string | undefined` (this is a union type, meaning the value can either be `string` or `undefined`)

```
export const useSomething =()=> {
    const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState<string | undefined>(
        undefined //getting error here
    );
    const toggle = (itemId: string) => {
        setItemId(itemId);
        return {toggle, itemId};

    }
 }
```

This may lead to errors in other places (where you expect a string, but not `undefined` is also an option but you should fix those to handle `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Simple!
Step 1: Declare something like this

```
const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState<string> as it is .
```

where we are passing values in component , there provide a condition Prop as a value

```
  interface ChildPropType ={
itemId?:string,
anotherId?: string;
toggle:boolean
```

}

```
function Child(props:ChildPropType) {
return (
    <Button onClick={() => toggle(anotherId || '')/>
);
```

}

Error is because it could be either String or undefined but as ***

> setState is Asynchronous in nature

***  so react compile they check there is possibility that value could be undefined as well so we need make condition check for child component where it will consume that state value.

Hope it will help :)